# Facebook login exception on live apk

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Facing facebook login error on live APK, **which was running fine from past 3 years**, Suddenly getting exception on facebook login,

```
{HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Missing Permissions}
```

Following is the login implementation,

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            if (!isFinishing()) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                        if (json != null) {
                            // ...
                        } else {
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                            Log.d("FBERROR"+response.getError());
                            DDRuntimeException.setLogs(new Throwable("FBResponseNULL"));
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Following permission is requested are approved in facebook developer.

**NOTE**  Facebook developer account is in live mode.

Answer (score 1):

This got fixed,

I was requesting for the 'cover' field in graph api request, Facebook has deprecated the key without any notice.

You can check the issue generated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/297556258061769/)

Comment: Ya , So many logins might have broken  now , We need to push an update just for this